# How to use zurb foundation 4 large layout for print

Tags: layout, printing, zurb-foundation

How can i get my > 768px layout to work for printing? I seems to fallback to a mobile layout. I'm using the fix https://github.com/zurb/foundation/issues/1285 
Any help would be highly appreciated.  Thnx.

Comment: So.. the fix does not work for you, or are you looking for another solution?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The fix works, but it shows a mobile, single column layout. I want to use my large multicolumn layout. Any thoughts?

Comment: If you post your solution as your answer, we can even vote it up!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just after @import "settings"; in app.scss add:

```
$small: "print, screen and (min-width:"#{$small-screen}")";
```

This seems to work.

Comment: Glad you worked it out - feel free to 'accept the answer', even if it's your own.

Comment: this worked for me but it seems more appropriate to override it in the _settings.scss file.

Comment: Does anyone provide the code for non scss file? I have the same problem but I am using foundation.css

Comment: Not sure about app.scss or _settings.scss, I put it after `@import 'foundation'` in foundation_and_overrides.scss.  Should work after an update that way.  Thanks.